# Parameter Estimation in Generalized Linear Mixed Models

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, random-effects-model

Let us assume a generalized linear mixed model with a binary dependent variable $y_{i, t } $ that is explained by a fixed effect matrix X and a simple random intercept for each individual $i$

$y_{i,t} = x_{i,t}'\beta +\alpha_i  + \epsilon_{i,t} \hspace{35pt} \alpha \sim N(0, \sigma_{\alpha})$

As far as I know, when we want to estimate the fixed and random effects via maximum likelihood, we have to integrate out the random effects over every individual so that the log likelihood becomes

$ LL(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^N \log \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \prod_{t=1}^{T_i}F(y_{i,t}|\alpha_i, \beta) g(\alpha_i) d \alpha_i \right)$

However, if we integrate the random intercepts out, the $\alpha$ disappears and we can only solve for $\beta$. How do we estimate $\alpha$ then?

Comment: The parameters of your model are $(\beta, \sigma_\alpha)$ and not $(\beta,\alpha)$. The integrals over the random effects are function of both $\beta$ and $\sigma_\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. You are right, the random intercepts are not parameters. But still they take on values, right? How do we determine those values?

Comment: The model should be $y_{i,t} = x_{i,t}'\beta +\alpha_i + \epsilon_{i,t} \hspace{35pt} \alpha_i \sim N(0, \sigma_{\alpha}) \hspace{35pt} \epsilon_{i,t} \sim N(0, \sigma) $ and $\epsilon_{i,t}$ and $\alpha_i$ are independent.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a binary outcome variable you typically use a link function to connect the probability of a positive response to the linear predictor that includes the random effects, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\left \{ \begin{array}{l}
\log \displaystyle \frac{\pi_{it}}{1 - \pi_{it}} = x_{it}^\top \beta + z_{ij}^\top b_i,\\\\
\pi_{it} = \Pr(y_{it} = 1 \mid b_i),\\\\
b_i \sim \mathcal N(0, D),
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
where $x_{it}$ is a design vector for the fixed effects coefficients $\beta$, and $z_{it}$ a design vector for the random effects $b_i$.

When you fit the model under maximum likelihood, the random effects are unobserved variables that are integrated out from the expression of the log-likelihood of the model, i.e.,
$$\ell(\theta) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \log \int \prod_t p(y_{it} \mid b_i; \beta) \; p(b_i; D) \; db_i,$$
where $\theta^\top = (\beta^\top, \mbox{vech}(D))$ denotes the parameters of the model. The integral does not have a closed-form solution, and is typically approximated using either the Laplace approximation or adaptive Gaussian quadrature (the latter is considered better).

The random effects are estimated in a second step using empirical Bayes methodology, that is, for $i = 1, \ldots, n$ they are estimated as the modes of the posterior distribution 
$$p(b_i \mid y_i) \propto p(y_i \mid b_i; \hat \beta) \; p(b_i; \hat D),$$
where $\hat \beta$ and $\hat D$ denote the maximum likelihood estimates of $\beta$ and $D$, respectively.